# fgets() breaks string into 2 lines

Tags: c, fgets

I am an absolute beginner to programming and I am starting with the C language. I am currently using the Beginning Programming with C for Dummies book by Dan Gookin.

When doing an exercise with fgets() the following occurred.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];

    printf("Who are you? ");
    fgets(name,10,stdin);
    printf("Glad to meet you, %s.\n",name);

    return(0);
}
```

The expected result should be a name with a full stop at the end and what is happening is that the full stop carries over to the next line like shown below.

[image]

I am using the code blocks IDE on Ubuntu

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer."

Comment: Just remove the newline from `fgets`?

Comment: Please don't post images for simple text output — include the text output in the question.  Treat it as code.

Comment: A reliable way to get rid of the newline is `name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OP would also have to include `<string.h>` to use `strcspn()`.

Comment: @RoadRunner: true, that would also be needed.

Comment: First of all let me thank you for your answers, I'm sorry It took me so long to come back here. The thing is I might not have explained myself correctly. Even if I remove the \n character (line9) the full stop after the %s still goes to a new line. And even stranger, at least to me, If I change the length of the string to 3 instead of 10 and write my name (Miguel) what is output is Mi. The first 2 letters of my name and the full stop. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: show your modified code that takes into account the above comments and still fails.

Answer (score 1):

You typed Miguel and then pressed `ENTER`. `name` now holds `Miguel\n`, in which `\n` stands for the `ENTER` you just pressed, since `ENTER` counts as a character too. If you want to remove it, you'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok(name, "\n")`

Comment: This would fail if the user typed more then 8 characters before pressing the enter key or hit Ctrl-D.